# Craft Commerce: discount taxation

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, discounts, tax

Is there a way in Craft Commerce to apply discounts to the net order total (eg the subtotal/before tax is applied to the order)? Out of the box this seems to discount from the basket/order total.

[image: sample screenshot (back-end]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to bottom of this - is down to how the Tax Rules are set-up.
Taxable Subject was set to Line Item but should have been set to Order Total.